# can't execute curl_easy_perform twice on Windows2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio, libcurl

I installed libcurl-7.28.1 on a Windows 2008 server and followed instructions in "Using libcurl with SSH support in Visual Studio 2010". I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 actually. I could upload a file to a Linux server (with curl_easy_perform()) using the sample code. But the next code (curl_easy_cleanup()) has crushed. Same thing occured when I tried to upload another file using the same CURL handle.("crushed" means an exception caught by Visual Studio.) Of course I can upload another file using a new CURL handle, but can't reduce the overhead of
connection with that code.
What do I needed to reuse the CURL handle?

I had done a few more thing what was not in that book. I had to add libssh2.lib in *Additional Dependencies* and had to copy ssleay32.dll,libeay32.dll,libssh2.dll to the Debug folder of the Visual Studio project. I copied them from libcurl-7.18.0 package. I couldn't find them elsewhere.